# date using either raw_input() or input() coming up as integer

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

New to Python and have read so many other SO questions that I feel like I am missing something with how to massage user input to string format. I have this simple code and I get the `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'` so I added exception handiling and am getting **error** everytime. **I have tried almost everything with the str(), datetime() and std.readline() and nothing**.

```
 def dateConverter(userDate):
        try:
            #split the substrings for month day year
            date = userDate.split("/")
            #day
            day = date[:2]
            #month
            month = date[3:5]#[ beginning : beginning + LENGTH]
            months = {1:'January', 2:'February', 3:'March', 4:'April', 5:'May', 6:'June', 7:'July', 8:'August', 9:'September', 10:'October', 11:'November', 12:'December'}
            for key,value in months:
                month=value
            #year
            year = date[4:]
            print(str(month + ' ' + day + ',' + year))
            return True
        except:
            print('Error')
            return False
print('Enter a date in the format: mm/dd/yyyy \n')
    userInput = raw_input()
    dateConverter(userInput)

main()
```

*Note: I have both Python27 and Python34 installed on Win7*
**Edit**

---

[vaibhav-sagar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2896874/vaibhav-sagar) was correct, I wasn't slicing the string the right way and had nothing to do with the input. **Although, I have Python27 & Python34 installed and even though I set my variable path to Python34 I have to use raw_input() which I heard was deprecated in Python34** so look out for that too. That is what was stumping me! Sorry, this was my second look at Python so it was really new territory. I actually got the slicing examples from another SO answer so that is what I get for assuming. Here is the solution:

```
 #custom date converter func
    def dateConverter(userDate):
        try:
            #split the substrings for month day year
            date = userDate.split("/")
            #day
            day = date[1]#[ beginning : beginning + LENGTH]
            #month
            month = date[0]
            months = {1:'January', 2:'February', 3:'March', 4:'April', 5:'May', 6:'June', 7:'July', 8:'August', 9:'September', 10:'October', 11:'November', 12:'December'}
            month=months[int(month)]
            #year
            year = date[2]
            print(month + ' ' + day + ',' + year)
            return True
        except:
            print('Error')
            return False
```

Next step is to validate using re to validate the  date is valid

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full traceback of the error you're seeing? You might need to remove (or comment out) the `try`/`except` statements that you're currently using to suppress the error (a bad idea when you're troubleshooting).

Answer (score 1):

I am using Python 3.3.5 and getting a different error. An exception is being raised at

```
for key, value in months:
```

Because iterating over a dictionary yields only keys, and not keys and values. What you want can be accomplished by:

```
for key, value in months.items():
```

More generally, your issues seem unrelated to your massaging of user input. This can be verified by using IDLE or another REPL. For example:

```
>>> someDate = '12/10/2014'
>>> date = someDate.split('/')
>>> date
['12', '10', '2014']
>>> day = date[:2]
>>> day
['12', '10']
>>> month = date[3:5]
>>> month
[]
>>> year = date[4:]
>>> year
[]
```

Python's slice syntax is doing something different to what I think you want. I also think you don't need a for loop, instead you can do:

```
month = months[int(month)]
```

This will assign the month name to `month`, like you expect. A function that does what I think you want would look something like this:

```
def dateConverter(userDate):
    #split the substrings for month day year
    date = userDate.split("/")
    #day
    day = date[1]
    #month
    month = date[0]
    months = {1:'January', 2:'February', 3:'March', 4:'April', 5:'May', 6:'June', 7:'July', 8:'August', 9:'September', 10:'October', 11:'November', 12:'December'}
    month = months[int(month)]
    #year
    year = date[2]
    print(str(month + ' ' + day + ',' + year))
    return True
```

I hope that helps.